# how to start an activity in handler

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

trying to trigger an Activity from a handler.
my other option is triggering from a broadcastReceiver.
this is what ive tried and it doesnt work.

```
public void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Log.v(tag,"handling message.........");

    String messageString = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

    C2DMMessage newC2DMMessage = new C2DMMessage(messageString);


    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,popad.class);
    context.startActivity(mIntent);

    String message_body = String.valueOf(newC2DMMessage.getParamValue("message_body"));
    Toast.makeText(context, "message was recieved!!!!: '" + message_body + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

open to suggestions for a better way to start an activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any errors you get in Logcat would be most helpful in your questions
Try changing :

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,popad.class);
context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

To :

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context,popad.class);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help please mark the answer as accepted so I can get some moar points! :) :) :)

Comment: could u explain what u have changed and what was my mistake?

Comment: Sure, Calling startActivity() not within an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.  In your case,  I think, you are using a reciever to start some activity in your app for the first time. Or maybe not as I cant see how you implemented things.  Either way, here is a super awesome article for you to check out and love : http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/